# Complex Roots Made Visible

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone point me to a pdf of the article, "Complex Roots Made Visible", by Norton and Lotto.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here you go. This was ever so difficult to find :)](http://bfy.tw/zgI)

Comment: That was awesome!!!

Comment: Thanks AJ. I've been to this site, and there is a nice presentation, however, there is no link (that I can find) to the original paper by Norton & Lotto.

Comment: Is this not it? http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0746834213661.di020712.02p0024j.pdf

Comment: This is definitely the first two pages, but based upon the text there appears to be more. My reference only sites these two pages as well, so I assume that I would need to purchase the entire article. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Ron According to the journal the article is only covers 2 pages http://www.jstor.org/stable/2686333?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: I believe that is all that there is to the article. The article is in the category "Classroom Capsules" which are short little bits of mathematics meant to intrigue/help students.

Comment: I guess I don't really know. However, the final sentence appears to be truncated, which leads me to assume that there is indeed more. In any event I thank all of you for spending your time on my question.

Comment: That's a different article. The next article starts immediately after yours.

Comment: Success! I was able to get into Jstor and found page 250 which completes the article.  Thanks again all.